# How to authenticate a standalone javascript game in facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, social-networking

I have a standalone JS game and want people to post their scores on FaceBook. I created an FB game ID. Now I want to let people log in via FB and post their scores. I thought this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/ should be the way. However this does not seem to work. Can anyone please guide me how to proceed?
Thanks